# Upload multipart form data with filename in Request Payload

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, angular-file-upload

I am still confused about different method of uploading files. The backend server is not under my control but I can upload a file using Swagger page or Postman. That means the server is functioning OK. But when I use AngularJS to do the upload, it doesn't work.

Here is what works using Postman to test. I am just using `form-data`:

[image]

Notice that Request Headers has Content-Type as multipart/form-data. But the Request Payload has `filename` and Content-Type as image/png.

Here is my code:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: ApiUrlFull + 'Job/Item?smartTermId=0&name=aaa1&quantity=1&ApiKey=ABC',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
  transformRequest: function(data) { 
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', params.imageData);
    return fd; 
  }
})
```

`params` is just an object with file url in `imageData`.

My code also send similar URL params (so we can ignore that causing issues). But the Request Payload is base64 and it looks different as it is missing the `filename` field.

[image]

I have zero control of the backend and it is written in .NET.

So I guess my question is: Using Angular (either $http or $resource), how do I modify the request so that I am sending the correct Request Payload as how Postman does it? I cannot figure out how to reverse engineer this.

I have tried this https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload and it actually did OPTIONS request first before POST (assuming CORS issue). But the server gave 405 error for OPTIONS.

Comment: You need an actual `File`(or just a `Blob`) object to send to get the effect in the first request, `params.imageData` is a string.

Comment: `params.imageData` is just `file://` URL from the `input type=file`. Or do you mean something else that I am not thinking?

Comment: From what you posted `params.imageData` is a base64 encoded png, which is a string. To get FormData to post the data the way you want it has to be a File object or a Blob object. I`fd.append('file', blob_from_imageData);` search SO for question to convert a data url to a blob.

Comment: How did you solve it? Facing the same problem. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use something along the line of:

```
<input type="file" name="file" onchange="uploadFile(this.files)"/>
```

And in your code:

```
$scope.uploadFile = function(files) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    //Take the first selected file
    fd.append("file", files[0]);
    var uploadUrl = ApiUrlFull + 'Job/Item?smartTermId=0&name=aaa1&quantity=1&ApiKey=ABC';
    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined },
        transformRequest: angular.identity
    }).success( ...all right!... ).error( ..damn!... );

};
```

Answer (score 0):

My need was a follows.

- In the form there is a default picture.
- Clicking the picture opens a file select window.
- When the user selects a file, it is uploaded right away to the server.
- As soon as I get a response that the file is valid display the picture to the user instead of the default picture, and add a remove button next to it.
- If the user clicks on an existing picture, the file select window reopens.

I tried to use a few code snippets on github that didn't solve the problem, but guided me in the right way, And what I ended up doing is as so:

> Directive

```
angular.module("App").directive('fileModel', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.files = {};
            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
            var modelSetter = model.assign;

            // I wanted it to upload on select of file, and display to the user.
            element.bind('change', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });

                // The function in the controller that uploads the file.
                scope.uploadFile();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

> Html

```
<div class="form-group form-md-line-input">
    <!-- A remove button after file has been selected -->
    <span class="icon-close pull-right"
          ng-if="settings.profile_picture"
          ng-click="settings.profile_picture = null"></span>
    <!-- Show the picture on the scope or a default picture -->
    <label for="file-pic">
        <img ng-src="{{ settings.profile_picture || DefaultPic }}"
             class="clickable" width="100%">
    </label>

    <!-- The actual form field for the file -->
    <input id="file-pic" type="file" file-model="files.pic" style="display: none;" />
</div>
```

> Controller

```
$scope.DefaultPic = '/default.png';

$scope.uploadFile = function (event) {
        var filename = 'myPic';
        var file = $scope.files.pic;
        var uploadUrl = "/fileUpload";

        file('upfile.php', file, filename).then(function (newfile) { 
            $scope.settings.profile_picture = newfile.Results;
            $scope.files = {};
        });
};

function file(q, file, fileName) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('fileToUpload', file);
    fd.append('fn', fileName);
    fd.append('submit', 'ok');

    return $http.post(serviceBase + q, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
    }).then(function (results) {
        return results.data;
    });
}
```

Hope it helps.

P.S. A lot of code was striped from this example, if you need clarification just comment.